# Website to Track Project's Progress

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

This ASP.NET MVC website is for my professor to track my progress on my Checkers app.  This is the first time I have build an ASP.NET website entirely on my own, and I would like a review to make sure I am doing everything in the best way possible.

First, my HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private T Deserialize<T>(string filePath)
    {
        var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        return jss.Deserialize<T>(data);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var announcements = Deserialize<ListOfItems<Announcement>>(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Announcements.json"));
        var latestAnnouncement = announcements.Items.Last();
        if (DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(7)) > latestAnnouncement.AnnouncementDate)
        {
            latestAnnouncement = null;
        }

        return View(latestAnnouncement);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Reports()
    {
        var reports = Deserialize<ListOfItems<BiweeklyReport>>(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Reports.json"));

        return View(reports.Items);
    }

    public ActionResult Resources()
    {
        var resources = Deserialize<ListOfItems<Resource>>(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Resources.json"));

        return View(resources.Items);
    }

    public ActionResult Announcements()
    {
        var announcements = Deserialize<ListOfItems<Announcement>>(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Announcements.json"));

        return View(announcements.Items);
    }
}
```

My models are as follows:

First, a generic class for easy serialization of a list of items:

```
[Serializable]
public class ListOfItems<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And a set of items to serialize.  To keep this post slim, I will only post one:

```
[Serializable]
public class Announcement
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime AnnouncementDate { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

My views are all either static information or a simple iteration over a list of data; here is my view for the above model class:

```
@model List<Announcement>
@using ITM3804Website.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Announcements";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<hr />

@{
    var orderedAnnouncements = Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.AnnouncementDate);
    foreach (var announcement in orderedAnnouncements)
    {
         <p>
             <strong class="announcement-title">@announcement.Title</strong><br/>
             <i>@announcement.AnnouncementDate.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy")</i><br/>
             @announcement.Content
         </p>

        if (announcement != orderedAnnouncements.Last())
        {
             <hr/>
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to talk about your View while I'm on mobile and thinking about it. Just like regular C# code we should definitely define structure for our Razor code. The first thing that rubs me wrong is that `@using` statement. I really don't like it because you **only** need it for the `@model` declaration at the top of the file. I would just get rid of it and explicitly specify the model full type.

Next, I really don't like the `@{ }` block with the `foreach` and such in it. Generally I just prefer to prefix each code block with `@whatever` instead. This helps create a more consistent convention throughout. (Right now you mix `code` and `@code` in your view which is generally bad.)

As far as the HTML itself, we've started leaning more on CSS to do the styling for things, so elements like `strong` and `i` should be `span class="title"` then in your CSS `.title` would have `font-weight: bold;`.

Let's talk about your serialization:

> ```
> private T Deserialize<T>(string filePath)
> {
>     var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
>     var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
>     return jss.Deserialize<T>(data);
> }
> ```

You always call it as `Deserialize<T>(Server.MapPath(...))`, so let's encapsulate that:

```
private T DeserializeAppData<T>(string file) =>
    Deserialize<T>(Server.MapPath($"~/App_Data/{file}.json"));
```

Then call it as `DeserializeAppData<T>("Reports")`. Much simpler, straightforward and to the point. You still have the other `Deserialize<T>` method, in case you need it for other things.